# Windows batch scripting replace special character to character encoding format

Tags: batch-file

I am replacing special character to its character encoding by cmd batch scripting , it is working for the most of special characters, below examples are working -

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set password=!pass:@=%%40!
set password=!password:^&=%%26!
```

O/p - `@ will show as %40`

Question -- But for these `!,*,",!,~` characters are not replacing with character encoding .

Refer this list - https://grox.net/utils/encoding.html

Please help on this

Comment: These !, | , *, ", ~

Answer (score 1):

This will be difficult and/or inefficient with pure batch. The solution pointed to by MichaelS can be adapted to work, but there is a simpler way.

[JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) is a hybrid JScript/batch script that performs regular expression search and replace. It is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. It has options that allow you to specify a delimited list of search terms, and a delimited list of replacement values.

The following code assumes your PATH points to a folder that contains [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044).

```
for /f "eol=| delims=" %%A in (
  'jrepl "\x21 \x22 * | ~" "%%21 %%22 %%2A %%7C %%7E" /t " " /l /x /s password'
) do set "password=%%A"
```

The FOR /F EOL option is set to one of the characters that is encoded so that you don't have to worry about the initial character causing the result to be ignored.

The first JREPL argument is the space delimited list of search terms.

The second argument is the spaces delimited list of replacement values.

The `/T " "` option specifies that the search and replace arguments are space delimited lists of search and replace terms.

The `/L` option specifies that the search terms are treated as literals

The `/X` option enables escape sequences within the search term, even though the `/L` option is used.

The `/S password` option specifies that the source input string is read from the password variable.

It is trivial to add additional search and replace values to the space delimited lists. If you want to include a space in the search or replace list, then you must alter the `/T` option delimiter to a character that is not used in either list.

The `!` is represented as an escape sequence just in case delayed expansion is enabled. The `"` is represented as an escape sequence because quote literals cannot be passed to JREPL.

One really nice feature of this solution is it does all replacements in one pass, so you do not have to worry about the order of the search/replace terms.